# Safe to test circuit breaker is working by overloading it?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Is it safe to test a 20-amp circuit breaker is working by overloading it? The reason I ask is because I purchased a 11-amp window air conditioner. If someone plugs a vacuum into a outlet on the same circuit I want to ensure it trips.

Comment: Eh? You're making some rather drastic assumptions about said vacuum...

Comment: breakers don't always trip immediately, a 1000w vacuum together with a 11A AC is only barely above 20A which is not a fire hazard by itself. So you probably have a few minutes before it trips. Especially if the AC is in the off part of the duty cycle.

Comment: Why do you want to ensure it trips if the AC and a vacuum are running at the same time? Is there something special about that vacuum?

Answer (score 2):

A breaker is designed to safely trip out on overload. That being said, anytime you have a breaker trip out on overload you are doing some damage to a breaker and it actually changes some of the breaker specs and properties. Also as mentioned all breakers have time curves that trip breakers under certain conditions. For example if a 20A breaker is loaded to 25A it may take up to 2 minutes to trip, where a direct short causes an instantaneous trip.

The best way to test a breaker in the field is to use an amp meter and it should be sophisticated enough measure peak, constant and average amperages of both the ac and vacuum. It will usually trip at startup so measure the peak at the ac startup. Then measure the vacuum startup and do the math. If you have the breakers time curves you can check on how long the overload will hold.

If you really want to make sure the AC is the only thing to be used on a particular circuit. Is first make it a separate circuit for that equipment only and use a simplex outlet instead of a duplex.

Comment: Do you have any article regarding the damage happening to circuit breakers during the overload and the inner working of the process? Thank you!

Comment: @mishap - As far as publications go, most breaker manufacturers publish Training Manuals on Molded Case Circuit Breakers which are usually included in training classes, but they are a little heavy (boring) unless you want to take a study course on it. I really don't know of any short version unless you just want to look at a manufacturers specification sheet. sorry